# log indicating the project delete operation in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I have my own Google Cloud account, where I have created three projects, I have deleted one of the projects, ex ProjectA. I need to know where that "delete operation" log for that project is stored and the identity of the resource which deleted it.

Since it is my personal account, I don't have any organization, just the projects. Where can I find the logs and the time in which it was deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is regarding retrieving logs for deleted projects. Logs are recorded on a per project basis according to [resource manager audit logging information](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/audit-logging). The only ways to view logs from a deleted project would be [restoring the project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project),if you have a 30-day recovery period and [exporting audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#exporting_audit_logs).

Comment: Hi Thanks for this information, on exporting the audit logs, can the audit logs be exported to a bucket in a different project, or a database in a different project, as if I delete the project the bucket and database in the project would also get deleted , so the audit logs also would not be present

Comment: Actually for the above comment, I made I got this piece of info: In the Logs Viewer, you can also use the Custom destination option when creating an export to send your logs from one project to a destination in another project. For more information, go to creating sinks. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export but still I have a question when the project itself is deleted will the sink which is created inside that project make that delete operation entry and delete or will it get deleted before logging?

Comment: Exporting the logs to cloud pub/sub in a different project did it

Comment: Considering sink, exporting happens for new log entries only, we cannot export log entries that Logging received before the sink was created.https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export#how_sinks_work